# Xamarin - Native Android to PCL

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have a class in my Native Android profile called "LoginRenderer.cs", now i have some code that gets user Email and username. After that is over, it tries to navigate (with parameters) the user to a view page called "UserProfileINC" (this includes the .cs and .xaml file). UserProfileINC also has a ViewModel classs named after it called UserProfileINC_vm.cs.

Now the **problem** is that when the user is navigated to the next view, the UserProfile.xaml view does not get displayed. I can see that the breakpoints reach the UserProfileINC.cs and UserProfileINC_vm.cs pages but cant see anything on screen except white background.

**This is how i navigate:**

```
NavigationPage nav = new NavigationPage(new UserProfileINC(email, id, username));
```

**My code for LoginRenderer.cs that deals with the Native android part:**

```
if (showLogin && OAuthConfig.User == null)
            {
                showLogin = false;

                //Create OauthProviderSetting class with Oauth Implementation .Refer Step 6
                OAuthProviderSetting oauth = new OAuthProviderSetting();

                if (providername == "Twitter")
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    var auth = oauth.LoginWithProvider(providername);

                    // After facebook,google and all identity provider login completed 
                    auth.Completed += async (sender, eventArgs) =>
                    {
                        if (eventArgs.IsAuthenticated)
                        {
                            //try
                            //{
                            //    LoginManager.Instance.LogInWithReadPermissions(activity, new string[] { "public_profile", "email"}); //Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email"));
                            //}
                            //catch(Exception ex)
                            //{
                            //    await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("ERROR!!!", ex.Message, ":(");
                            //}
                            //OAuthConfig.User = new UserDetails();

                            //OAuthConfig.User.Token = eventArgs.Account.Properties["access_token"];//oauth_token"];
                            //OAuthConfig.User.ExpiresIn = eventArgs.Account.Properties["expires_in"];


                            var request = new OAuth2Request("GET", new Uri("https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=first_name,last_name,gender,email"), null, eventArgs.Account);
                            var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();

                            var obj = JObject.Parse(response.GetResponseText());

                            //LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(fragmentOrActivity, Arrays.asList("email"));
                            var id = obj["id"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");

                            //Store ID as password
                            loginPage.ID = id;

                            var firstname = obj["first_name"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");
                            var lastName = obj["last_name"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");
                            var gender = obj["gender"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");

                            loginPage.Email = "Facebook";
                            var email = "Facebook";


                            activity = this.Context as Activity;
                            //?Should it be here too?

                            await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Welcome", firstname + " " + lastName, "Thank you!");
                            await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Your ID", id, "Thank you again!");
                            string username = firstname + lastName;
                            await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Profile completion", "As this is your first time, please complete your profile", "OK");
                            //Having the Facebook user id as the password

                            NavigationPage nav = new NavigationPage(new UserProfileINC(email, id, username));

                            //await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new UserProfileINC(email, id, username));

                            //OAuthConfig.SuccessfulLoginAction.Invoke();


                        }
                        else
                        {
                            await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Cancel!", "Login Canceled", "Go Back!");
                            // The user cancelled
                        }
                    };


                    activity.StartActivity(auth.GetUI(activity));

                }
```

**UserProfileINC.xaml :**

```
namespace LoginSystem.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class UserProfileINC : ContentPage
    {
        //TraditionalLogin FirstTime
        public UserProfileINC(string e, string p, string u)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, false);
            BindingContext = new UserProfileINC_vm(e, p, u);
        }
    }
}
```

**UserProfileINC.cs :**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:LoginSystem.ViewModels"
             BackgroundColor="Azure" 
             x:Class="LoginSystem.Views.UserProfileINC">
    <ContentPage.Content>

        <StackLayout Padding="10" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <!--Gender Country Address Province Postal-->
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label Text="Gender" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center"></Label>
                <Entry Text="{Binding Gender}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" />
                <Label Text="Country" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center"></Label>
                <Entry Text="{Binding Country}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />
                <Label Text="Address" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center"></Label>
                <Entry Text="{Binding Address}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" />
                <Label Text="Province" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center"></Label>
                <Entry Text="{Binding Province}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" />
                <Label Text="Postal" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center"></Label>
                <Entry Text="{Binding Postal}" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" />
            </Grid>

            <Button Text="Done!" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Blue" TextColor="White" Command="{Binding Button_Clicked}"/>

        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**UserProfileINC_vm.cs :**

```
public UserProfileINC_vm(string e, string i, string u)
{
    _email = e;
    _id = i;
    _username = u;

    //It Comes here and stops!!!!
}
```

Comment: I can't see a problem with the code, but where are the grid elements being bound? Whenever I see a silent failure during view loading, it's usually a bad binding (mistyped name, invalid value).

Comment: simply creating a new instance of NavigationPage does not actually cause the current page to change

Comment: Jason, should I set App.Navigation to that line? Could you please help with a line of code.

Comment: Slepz, I couldnt find any naming problem.

Comment: What do you use as MainPage? Is it wrapped in NavigationPage? If yes what was wrong with   await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync? As @Jason said you need to Push the page after you create one

Comment: Whats wrong with await App.Current.MainPage.Naviagtion.PushAsync is that, i don't see the view for that navigated page. All i see is a blank page.

Comment: Did you wrap your MainPage into NavigationPage?

Comment: Yes, This is what i have in my App.xaml :                                                
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainView());

Comment: You didn't post that code. To help I will need a project to debug if you want to share it

Comment: How would you like me to share? Its a rather heavy file. Never shared a project before.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148345/discussion-between-yuri-s-and-tigerlioncheetah).